# Power BI LOOKUPVALUE with a column of values for the search items? (VLOOKUP alternative)

Tags: powerbi

In Power BI, I need to create a `VLOOKUP` alternative. From the research I've done, this is done with the `LOOKUPVALUE` function, but the problem is that function needs one specific `SEARCH ITEM`, which isn't super helpful in a `VLOOKUP` type scenario where you have a full column of values to search for?

Given these two tables, connected through the `user_name` and `first_name` columns:

[image: startingTables]

...what's the formula needed in order to create a new column in the `Employee_Table` called `phone_call_group` by using the names as the search items in order to return the `group` they belong to? So how can I end up with this?

[image: desiredTable]

(Forget that the entries in each table are already sorted, needs to be dynamic). Will be back tomorrow to review solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Power BI you have relations between tables instead of Excel's VLOOKUP function.

In your case you just have to create a one-to-one relation between

`'Phone_Call_Table'[user_name]` and `'Employee_Table'['first_name]'`

[image]

With that you can add a **Calculated Column** to your `'Employee_Table'` using the following expression:

```
phone_call_group = RELATED(Phone_Call_Table[group])
```

and in the data view the table will look like this:

[image]

LOOKUPVALUE() is just a workaround if for other reasons you can't establish that relation. What you've been missing so far is that in a **Calculated Column** there is a **Row Context** which gives you exactly one value per row for the <search_value> (this is different from **Measures**):

```
alt_phone_call_group = 
    LOOKUPVALUE(
        Phone_Call_Table[group], 
        Phone_Call_Table[user_name], 
        Employee_Table[first_name]
    )
```

[image]